# rosbag play & tf extrapolation problems

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I wrote a program for collecting laser data from a bag (currently I'm using a bag from the gmapping node tutorial).

The bag is executed as usually:
rosbag play bag

No problems so far, I can visualize everything in rviz.
Problems are on the listener side.
The callback, rather basic, is the following:

```
void callBack(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg)
{
     tf::TransformListener listener;
     tf::StampedTransform trans;
     try
     {
        ros::Time time=msg->header.stamp;
        listener.waitForTransform("base_laser", "odom", time, ros::Duration(1));
        listener.lookupTransform("base_laser", "odom", time, trans);
            //Do something
      }
      catch(tf::TransformException ex)
      {
             ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
      }
}
```

In few words, it doesn't work, I always obtain:

```
Lookup would require extrapolation into the past
```

or

```
Lookup would require extrapolation into the future
```

I modified, by hand, the time variable value as follows:

```
ros::Time time=ros::Time(msg->header.stamp.sec+1);
```

Although it worked, to me is not a feasible or general solution.

Changing duration value didn't help either.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe did I forget some parameter for ROS to set?

Thanks for your help,

Tambo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100246/rosbag-play-&-tf-extrapolation-problems/) by [Tambo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3193/tambo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check for the return value of `waitForTransform()`:

```
bool success = listener.waitForTransform("base_laser", "odom", time, ros::Duration(1));
if (success) {
    listener.lookupTransform("base_laser", "odom", time, trans);
}
```

What happens is that `waitForTransform()` fails, but you still call `lookupTransform()`, so that's where the exceptions come from.

The next step is figuring out why your lookups time out. It's normal if that happens for the first few laser scans, since your TF listener wasn't yet buffering TF messages before your node got started. But after a very short while, these errors should disappear.

One thing to check is that you set the queue size of your laser scan subscriber to a small value (like 1). Otherwise, you'll have the following problem:

- The queue gets filled with laser scan messages from the "past" (i.e., the first second or so before the node was started).
- Your callback works through the queue one message at a time; since `waitForTransform()` times out, this takes 1 second per message.
- If you don't get a valid transform for the first 15 messages, all remaining messages will now fail because the TF buffer is only 15 seconds (or so) long.

This might also explain why adding 1 second "solves" the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have had a similar problem, my solution was to enable simulated time:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

Remember to set it for every ros session! And also remember to restart all your nodes after setting the parameter!
The only thing now is to also publish the clock from the bag file:

```
rosbag play --clock your.bag
```

Does that help?

Best
Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4